# Запятые при "скорее"

Tags: запятые

"Скорее, идём"  - правильно ли расставлены знаки? Обычно "скорее" обособляется в роли вводного слова, но здесь-то оно не вводное, а наоборот. Например :"Нас уже ждут! Скорее, идём!". Так чем же оно является?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаки правильные. Правильный ход мыслей. "Скорее" и близко здесь не вводное. Два простых предложения. Можно писать отдельно:

`Скорее! Идём!`

Это сравнительная степень к прил. `скорый` и к нареч. `скоро`. (из словаря)

Бывает и вместе:

`Идём скорее` = `пошли быстрее`.

Вводное:

`Нам, скорее, идти в ту сторону.`